# How to disable iOS bounce effect on scene load?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation, native-base, react-native-router-flux

My scene is bouncing whenever it is loaded. I want to disable the effect. I did many search but not able to find any solution. I am attaching gif for the animation here:

[image]

I tried searching for solution but didnt find anything. Following are my dependencies:

```
"react": "16.11.0",
"react-native": "0.62.2",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "~1.9.0",
"react-native-router-flux": "^4.2.0",
```

Finally after lots of debugging, I found that issue is with Nativebase. I have having different header for different pages:

Code like below:

App.js

```
<Router>
    <Stack key="root">
        <Scene openDrawer={this.openDrawer} initial navBar={HomeHeader} key="home" component={Home} />}
        <Scene openDrawer={this.openDrawer} navBar={Header} key="profile" component={User} />
        <Scene openDrawer={this.openDrawer} navBar={Header} path="/support" key="support" component={Support} />
    </Stack>
</Router>
```

HomeHeader:

```
<HeaderBase>

            <Left>
                <Button onPress={() => Actions.pop()} transparent>
                    <Icon name='arrow-back' />
                </Button>
            </Left>
            <Body>
                <Title onPress={() => Actions.support()}>HeaderBase</Title>
            </Body>
            <Right>
                <Button transparent>
                    <Icon name='menu' />
                </Button>
            </Right>
        </HeaderBase>
```

Header:

```
        <Left>
                <Button onPress={() => Actions.pop()} transparent>
                    <Icon name='arrow-back' />
                </Button>
            </Left>
            <Body>
                <Title onPress={() => Actions.support()}>HeaderBase</Title>
            </Body>
            <Right>
                <Button transparent>
                    <Icon name='menu' />
                </Button>
            </Right>
        </HeaderBase>
```

If I change `<Scene openDrawer={this.openDrawer} initial navBar={HomeHeader} key="home" component={Home} />}` to `<Scene openDrawer={this.openDrawer} initial navBar={Header} key="home" component={Home} />}` (make header same for all scene) works.

Comment: Considering this happens to your code, you might have to share some code or create some sample code to demonstrate the issue

Comment: @manishg actually issue is not with the code but the library `react-native-router-flux`. It does this bounce effect automatically and i am not able to find option to disable it. I raised the issue on Github but no reply

Comment: Do you see the same issue with flux example code?

Comment: @manishg finally i was able find the issue. Issue with with nativebase that when two different headers are used then it is creating bouncing.